# Why Fragment cannot be public static class?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments

I came across such problem: I wanted to have some Fragment as `public static` member of my `Activity` class.

But when I put such Fragment to layout file I receive such exception:

```
Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: 
Unable to instantiate fragment com.tst.MainActivity.InnerFragment:
make sure class name exists, is public, 
and has an empty constructor that is public
...
```

My code looks like this:

```
package com.tst;

public final class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public static class InnerFragment extends SherlockFragment {

        public InnerFragment() {
            super();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Layout file looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <fragment
        android:id="@+id/inner_fragment"
        android:name="com.tst.MainActivity.InnerFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now my question is why such code throws this Exception? As Android should be able to instanitate `InnerFragment` as it is `public static`. What is more I used to use `public static` Fragments and they worked, but on that time I added them programmatically in code not in xml definition.

Regards,
Michal

Comment: It might make more sense to use a `FrameLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but this piece of code is just to show the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
android:name="com.tst.MainActivity.InnerFragment"
```

to

```
android:class="com.tst.MainActivity$InnerFragment"
```